# Nokia VM Error: assertion failure ... assert(jvm_fast_globals.inline_allocation_top

Tags: java, java-me, virtual-machine, nokia-s40

I am trying to develop for Nokia S40 and am running into an assertion in the VM.  Has anyone run into this problem before?  I have never seen a VM assertion before.

```
 Emulator command: C:\Nokia\Devices\Nokia_Asha_SDK_1_0\bin\Nokia_Asha_SDK_1_0_em.exe -classpath      
 "C:\Users\agoyal3\AppData\Local\Temp\_mtj.tmpagoyal3\RMStest6987560855508617133.launch\RMStest.jar" 
 "C:\Users\agoyal3\AppData\Local\Temp\_mtj.tmpagoyal3\RMStest6987560855508617133.launch\RMStest.jad"
 Connecting to Running "Nokia Asha SDK 1.0" Instance #10002 ...
 connected to port 58012
 connected to port 58013
 MIDlet Saved: RMStest.jad inside Memory card://Midlets folder.
 MIDlet Saved: RMStest.jar inside Memory card://Midlets folder.
 check size of file resource usr/_memory_card/Midlets/RMStest.jar
 jarFileName is file:///usr/_memory_card/Midlets/RMStest.jar

 #
 # VM Error, assertion failure
 #
 # Error ID: /Wk2013W16_00rel/Wk2013W16_01localpush/s40_ng_wk16_01/yapas/java/cldc/src/vm/share/ROM/ROM.cpp, 356
 #
 # assert(jvm_fast_globals.inline_allocation_top == jvm_fast_globals.heap_start, "Required by permanent heap block")
 #
```

Comment: I too have the same problem..i use Nokia Asha SDK 1.1 in windows7 64 bit for the first time..and after installation i run the hello world project from Nokia eclipse application..it shows me assertion failed error..can u find a solution for this? If so please post the solution..thanks

Comment: I haven't been able to find a solution :(